# Trigger and click event with extra parameter not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason my custom jquery code is not working properly . What is the mistake in this code please check

```js
$(function(){
  $(".element1").on("click",function(a){
    if(a=="yes"){  alert("yes"); }
    alert("element1 is clicked");
  });

  $(".element2").on("click",function(){
    alert("element2 is clicked");
    $(".element1").trigger("click",["yes"]);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="element1" value="element1">
<input type="button" class="element2" value="element2">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vL3kskb5/

**Why yes is not alerting here ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function(a){
    if(a=="yes"){  alert("yes"); }
```

Since you doing it in your callback, click event will be the argument that you are receiving. Not the string you are passing. And an event object never be equal to  "yes"

Yes, what you have passed will be ignored unless you add new arguments.

```
$(".element1").on("click",function(a, v){

    if(v=="yes"){  alert("yes"); }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sureshatta/vL3kskb5/3/

Comment: so what is the solution for this ? how can i pass element ?

Comment: The answer of Suresh Atta is correct, but his fiddle still has `a=="yes"` instead of `v=="yes"`. Change that and it works ;)

Comment: @vi5ion Oh my Damn. Updated :D

Comment: @abilasher Ahh since you are my friend, I am giving this link to you. Please do not pass it to anyone. Here is the link http://api.jquery.com/trigger/